# using capacitor-community/electron to create desktop app with an installer, but installer missing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, electron, package.json, capacitor

I've created an app with ionic angular. I'm trying to build it using electron and to create an installer for the app.
I've run `ionic build` -> `npm i @capacitor-community/electron --save-dev` -> `npx cap add @capacitor-community/electron`

In the electron folder created, I've added some code to `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "financeapp",
  "productName":"Finance Monitor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An Amazing Capacitor App",
  "author": {
    "name": "",
    "email": ""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "build/src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && electron-rebuild",
    "electron:start-live": "node ./live-runner.js",
    "electron:start": "npm run build && electron --inspect=5858 ./",
    "electron:pack": "npm run build && electron-builder build --dir -c ./electron-builder.config.json",
    "electron:make": "npm run build && electron-builder build -c ./electron-builder.config.json -p always"

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor-community/electron": "^4.1.0",
    "chokidar": "~3.5.2",
    "electron-is-dev": "~2.0.0",
    "electron-serve": "~1.1.0",
    "electron-unhandled": "~3.0.2",
    "electron-updater": "~4.3.9",
    "electron-window-state": "~5.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^14.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "~22.11.7",
    "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.3",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "capacitor",
    "electron"
  ]
}
```

my`electron-builder.config.json`:

```
{
  "appId": "com.yourdoamnin.yourapp",
  "directories": {
    "buildResources": "resources"
  },
  "files": [
    "assets/**/*",
    "build/**/*",
    "capacitor.config.*",
    "app/**/*"
  ],
  "publish": {
    "provider": "github",
    "publishAutoUpdate": false
  },
  "nsis": {
    "allowElevation": true,
    "oneClick": false,
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
  },
  "win": {
    "target": "nsis",
    "icon": "assets/appIcon.ico"
  },
  "mac": {
    "category": "your.app.category.type",
    "target": "dmg"
  }
}
```

I then go to the electron folder directory and run: `npm run electron:make`, but it only creates a win_unpack folder without an installer and it shows this error:

```
 ⨯ Cannot detect repository by .git/config. Please specify "repository" in the package.json (https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository).
Please see https://electron.build/configuration/publish  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: Cannot detect repository by .git/config. Please specify "repository" in the package.json (https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository).
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I create the installer?

Comment: I've found the problem, its with the url under repository in package.json. But how do i remove this repository since i dont have a repository in github?

Answer (score 1):

Capacitor 3 @capacitor-community/electron has publishing built in and wants you to to specify a repo and add a GITHUB_TOKEN if using Github. If you don't want it to publish automatically just remove the publish section from electron-builder.config.json. It starts somewhere around line 12.